# Books on Infinite Dimensional Group Representations

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Quite self explanatory.  I'm looking for books on Infinite Dimensional Representation Theory.

I've got a good introductory functional analysis background, i.e Hilbert Spaces, Banach Spaces, open mapping theorem, Hahn Banach, Principle of Uniform Boundedness etc ...

I've got a good amount of Fourier Analysis, on the classic spaces, but I've never studied it on arbitrary groups.

As for Algebra, I've read just about all of Dummit and Foote.

Comment: why did you delete the last answer? It is not good to do so without explanation to who was working to help. Please in these cases give an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have zero familiarity with representation theory you probably want to start from something like `Theory of Group Representations` by *Naimark and Stern*, that contains representation of finite groups, compact groups and some Lie theory.

The most common source of irreducible infinite dimensional representations are induced representations, for which I recommend `A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis` by *Folland*. This book also contains basic C* algebras stuff, representation of locally compact abelian groups (i.e. the closest generalization of Fourier theory), representation of compact groups and a treatment of induced representations via the "Mackey machine".

If you are interested in applications, induced representations are used in the foundations of quantum field theory. If you have some familiarity with quantum mechanics you may find the new `Quantum Theory, Groups and Representations` by *Woit*, to be a fun reading while working through the more mathematical books above.